# DataGridView replace value

Tags: c#, datagridview

`dataGridView` has column `DataGridViewTextBoxColumn`, that reads from my database.
I need to replace one value to another, example:

If in field "date" I have value `"00.00.0000"` - I need to replace it to text `"absent"`.
How can i do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the `DataGridView.CellFormatting` event. With that you can easily format your cell and its text to whatever you need, based on its value. [This example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellformatting.aspx?ppud=4) explains it in detail.

Answer (score -1):

First get the data from the database then check if that value exist using `Contains()` then edit the value then show in your dataGridView.

Like this:

```
string checkDate;
if (checkDate == dt.Rows[0]["date"].ToString().Contains("00.00.0000"))
    checkDate = "absent";
```

Comment: @DownVoter Why downvote? I used this code in my program before.